# Can't drop a database even though it has no content

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to clear out old databases on my PC (had them for past projects) and whenever I try and drop any of them, I get the following error:

```
#1010 - Error dropping database (can't rmdir '.\aroma_cafe', errno: 41)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584458/error-dropping-database-cant-rmdir-test-errno-17

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in droping a database in MySQL (can't rmdir '.\oro', errno: 41)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947255/error-in-droping-a-database-in-mysql-cant-rmdir-oro-errno-41)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if the system is attempting to delete a directory/folder that doesn't exist. Have you already removed it manually? It could be that each database is stored in a directory and a list of all databases in some other file.. so if you have gotten rid of that data, only the reference remains.

Answer (score 0):

> I think there are files within that directory that is not related to
>   MySQL. One scenario might be, insufficient permissions. You might want
>   to delete that directory from the filesystem.

Should do comment though.